# Determine data type from CSV - Python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop

I'm new to Python and I'm having trouble using lists.

I expose my problem, as you can see, I have a datos.csv file with the following structure.

```
1,4.0,?,?,none,?
2,2.0,3.0,?,none,?
2,2.5,2.5,?,tc,39
```

Using this function I store the data on a list.

```
def main():
    lista = []
    with open('datos.csv','r') as f:
        for line in f:
           lista.append(line.strip().split(','))
    determinar_tipo(lista)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Up to this point, I have no problem.
However the problem comes when I have to determine the type of the elements.

Using this code, I can organize my list in columns

```
for columna in itertools.izip(*lista):
```

This code allows me to treat the data as columns, as indicated, here is an example of what I receibe from this 'for':

> ```
>   {'1','2','2'}
> {'4.0','2.0','2.5'}
>         .
>         .
>         .
> ```

As you can see is the same data from my csv file but structure by columns.

Ok, here is my problem.

I have to determine the type of each of the columns based on their argument, that is, suppose that the first column {'1', '2', '3'}, check the first element and that element is the type of that column, in this case the type of this column would be int.

Another example with {'4.0', '2', '2.5'}, I check the type of the primary element and determine that it is float.

For the case {'?', '?' , '?'} the type would be "indeterminate".

However, the problem comes with the signs '?', If I get a symbol of these, I have to check the next element of the column, it would be the element called 'word',  {'?', 'Word', '5'}, so the type of the column woulb be string.

This is the code I developed to verify it, but I did not finish determining the types correctly.

```
def determinar_tipo(lista):
  b = 0
  aux = []

  for columna in itertools.izip(*lista):
    if columna[0] != "?":   #If it's a number or string I save it
      aux.append(columna[0])
      print columna[0]
    else:                    #If it's '?'
      if len(columna) > b:
        b = b + 1
        if columna[b] != "?":
          aux.append(columna[b])
          b = 0
        else:
          b = b + 1
          print b
  #Correct code   
  for x in aux:
    try:
      var_type = type(int(x))
    except ValueError:
      try:
        var_type = type(float(x))
      except ValueError:
        var_type = type(x)
    print var_type
```

The first part of the code is responsible for storing in another list the element to determine the type for each of the columns, while the second part of the code is responsible for checking the type of each of those elements in the previous list.

In summary, I do not know how to make the 'for' return the correct element to be checked the type of the column correctly.

This is the correct answer for my data:

```
1  ,  4.0  ,   ?    ,      ?         ,   none   ,   ?
2  ,  2.0  ,  3.0   ,      ?         ,   none   ,   ?
2  ,  2.5  ,  2.5   ,      ?         ,    tc    ,   39
int  float   float     undetermined       string     int**
```

Comment: Is there any reason that 1, 2, 2 is an int? It could be a category that happens to be an int couldn't it (given the number of distinct values)? Or is it that only strings can ever be categories...

Comment: If it is a number without decimals, it will be 'int', if you have decimals it will be 'float', if it is any word like 'none' it will be of the 'string' type and if in the whole column only '?' we will have to indicate that it is of the 'indeterminate' type

Comment: Trying to determine the type from a set of values is quite hard as there can be thousand of cases that you may need to consider. For example, if a column is `(2, 3.5, 4)` it should be a `float`? Do I need to check every element in each column then? I would suggest to include the type info in the header row and then parsing the info according to it.

Comment: No no, it's easier, in the case in which you expose you check the first element, and you determine that the type will be only int, so that you will treat the rest of the values as int, that case I also believe if I am not mistaken that it will not be evaluated

Comment: Yes, but as @Adirio says, what if it's mixed... `(2, 3.5, 4)` everything can be a valid `float`, but if you treat them as `int`s then what do you do with `3.5`?

Comment: it is a case that will not be valued, that is, there can not be mixed type, if the first type that appears is int, the rest will also be the same, the same happens with floats, and with strings.

Comment: What does "not be valued" mean?

Comment: it is a case that will never exist, sorry for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369572/python-how-to-get-data-types-for-all-columns-in-csv-file has solutions for Pandas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the fucntions' names so that they make more sense:

```
def determinar_tipo(valor):
    if valor == '?':
        return 'undetermined'
    try:
        int(valor)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        return int
    try:
        float(valor)
    except ValueError:
        return str
    else:
        return float

def determinar_tipos(lista):
    aux = []
    for columna in itertools.izip(*lista):
        i = 0
        while i < len(columna) and columna[i] == '?':
            i += 1
        aux.append(columna[i])
    for i, each in enumerate(aux):
        aux[i] = determinar_tipo(each)
    return aux
```

Answer (score 2):

I made this approach. The important part is the generator. Let me know if it is helpful:

```
import itertools

lista =[
    ['1','4.0','?','?','none','?'],
    ['2','2.0','3.0','?','none','?'],
    ['2','2.5','2.5','?','tc','39']
]
def columnType(column):
    for val in column:
        if val != '?':
            try:
                float(val)
                if '.' in val: yield 'float'
                else: yield 'int'
            except ValueError:
                yield 'string'

for columna in itertools.izip(*lista):
    print columna, next(columnType(columna),'undetermined')
```

Giving as a result:

```
('1', '2', '2') int
('4.0', '2.0', '2.5') float
('?', '3.0', '2.5') float
('?', '?', '?') undetermined
('none', 'none', 'tc') string
('?', '?', '39') int
```

---

EDIT: Alternative function with @MaartenFabré suggestion:

```
import itertools

lista =[
    ['1','4.0','?','?','none','?'],
    ['2','2.0','3.0','?','none','?'],
    ['2','2.5','2.5','?','tc','39']
]

def columnType(column):
    for val in column:
        if val != '?':
            try:
                float(val)
                if '.' in val: return 'float'
                else: return 'int'
            except ValueError:
                return 'string'
    return 'undetermined'


for columna in itertools.izip(*lista):
    print columna, columnType(columna)
```

Comment: if you only use 1 value from the `columnType`, why use `yield`?

Comment: Correct, it works perfect, thanks mate. It was very helpful!

Comment: @MaartenFabré I want it to iterate until first valid occurrence. By using a generator I can achieve that. `next(columnType(columna),'undetermined')` gives me the first valid occurrence of `columnType(columna)` and if it can't be found it gives me the fallback `'undetermined'`.

Comment: adding a `return 'undefined'` to the end of the method achieves the same