# Python - How to get data types for all columns in CSV file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I am trying to get all data types from a CSV file for each column.
There is no documentation about data types in a file and manually checking will take a long time (it has 150 columns). 
Started using this approach:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file.csv')

>>> df.dtypes
a   int64
b   int64
c   object
d   float64
```

Is above approach good enough or there is a better approach to figure out data types?
 Also - file has 150 columns. When I type `df.types` - I can see only 15 or so columns. How to see them all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072285/determine-data-type-from-csv-python has (crude) non-Pandas solutions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depending on the size of your file, you might be able to save some time by only reading in the first few rows, using the `nrows` argument of [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv('/tmp/file.csv', nrows=25)
```

This is only useful if you know for sure that the types can be correctly inferred from the first n rows though, so be careful with this.

Once you have the data (or a subset of it) loaded into a DataFrame, you can view the types in a number of different ways, a few of which have been posted already, but I'll share another using a simple loop and [`iteritems`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.iteritems.html):

```
for name, dtype in df.dtypes.iteritems():
    print(name, dtype)

a int64
b float64
c object
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good way to do it.
It returns a Series object.
To see more rows you can use this one: 
`pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 250)`

Answer (score 0):

You could update the `max_info_columns` display option and use `DataFrame.info()`

```
pd.set_option('max_info_columns', 200)
df.info()
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some ways to do it. I like to use

```
df.dtypes
```

or

```
for i, v in enumerate(df.columns):
    print(i, v)
```