# Oracle from Excel - create column types dynamically

Tags: python, excel, oracle, csv

I need to make calculations on such a huge XLS table (~150 columns, ~1.000.000 rows) Excel freezes itself. I've decided to migrate the data into an Oracle table.

The columns have all the basic data types: int, floats, chars, strings, dates

I have two options:

1. I create the table manually with the proper data types. This may be the practical solution in the short run but tedious all the same.
2. For a long term solution (expecting many different types of excel tables in the future) I'd like to dynamically define the column types from the CSV.

I'm creating the table now with a default varchar tpye, using Python:

```
list_of_columns = parseFirstLine_CSV(.\data.csv)
columns = ['"%s" varchar2(255)' % n for n in list_of_columns]
sql = "create table SomeTableName (%s)" % ",".join(columns)
cursor.execute(sql)
```

Let's see this table. Let's assume that not every row is complete. The 'key' data are naturally available in the xls, this is just for an example.

```
ID      Company    Date         Quality
144     Apple      2019.01.03   ""
""      IBM        2019.01.03   200
105591  Oracle     2019.01.03   9
10R91   Microsoft  ""           113
10M99   ""         2019.01.03   3
1076a   Walmart    ""           ""
10M95   Lorem Co.  2019.01.03   3
```

I will use Python, but that's not the point.

**My theoretical question is:** how to determine the types if I'm not sure whether a line in the CSV is complete for every column (so I can't only look at the second csv line to get a list of types). Should I iterate through the CSV rows until I have all the types or is there a simpler algorithm for it?

I think it's cleaner to have the proper types than long varchar in my tables, so I can make cleaner queries in it.

EDIT: I will include the code in Python 3 after I'm done with implementation, I'm just interested in other opinions in the meantime.

Comment: You've given us a lot of information, but your question isn't clear. If I limited you to one sentence to summarize your issue, what would it be?

Comment: If you would like to determine the types in python of a value take a look at my answer

Comment: @JordanSinger
Quesiton is: How to create an Oracle table from excel without manually define the column types?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to get data types for all columns in CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369572/python-how-to-get-data-types-for-all-columns-in-csv-file)